# Xcode: MainMenu.nib (English) remains under SCM twisty after Commit Project

Tags: xcode

After I **Commit Entire Project**, in the left pane, under the *SCM* twisty, I still see the listing for *English*, which is described as *MainMenu.nib (English)* in the top right pane.

The file is already added to the repository, because I can select **SCM | Repositories** from the menu bar and then browse all the way to *<REPOSITORY>:<PROJECT HOME>/English.lproj/MainMenu.nib* which contains *classes.nib*, *info.nib*, *keyedobjects.nib*.

Hmm, actually, when I **Reveal in Finder** the working copy of *MainMenu.nib (English)*, and then in Finder, **Show Package Contents**, I see it only contains two files: *designable.nib*, and *keyedobjects.nib*.

That doesn't seem good. Any idea what is going on?

I am using Xcode 3.2.3 on OS X 10.6.4.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using .xib files and not .nib From [Apple's interface builder guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/IB_UserGuide/ApplicationBasics/ApplicationBasics.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005344-CH3-SW1)

> When you save an Interface Builder document, you save it using either the xib file or nib file format. Both formats store the same information but do so in different ways. Xib files are intermediate XML–based files that are intended for use only during the development of your project. Because they are text-based, you can save them in your source-code management system and perform diffs on them. During deployment, xib files are converted to nib files, which contain a binary version of the document data and are what your application actually loads at runtime. For any new projects, you should save your documents as xib files. For existing projects, you can also save your documents directly to the nib file format.

In this case it might not fix your issue but you should be able to see what the differences are.

Comment: I have [documented how I converted NIBs to XIBs](http://it-nonwhizzos.blogspot.com/2010/09/convert-nib-to-xib-in-interface-builder.html) at my blog.